# Digital signatures in MS Word

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, digital-signature

Do you know a way (f.e. library) in which I can generate signature lines in Microsoft Word document in Java as described for example [on Microsoft's page](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Add-or-remove-a-digital-signature-in-Office-documents-49af4304-bfe7-41bf-99c3-a5023bdab44a#bm3)
and later use it to sign a document multiple times? Each signature can be added at different point in time.

The crucial functionality I need to have is that a signer's name is added when a document is signed. In MS Word at the beginning you can define a number of 'signature lines' and then each person must right click on one signature box and click sign. The signer's name is filled in without breaking previous signatures.

I know how to sign documents in java (usually external xades signatures). I was also able to add multiple signatures at the same time using Apache POI as described here:
[How to programatically sign an MS office XML document with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522187/how-to-programatically-sign-an-ms-office-xml-document-with-java) but this will not work when changing a document (to update a signer's name). Maybe this functionality is also available in Apache POI?

In the attached print screen you can see (unfortunately in Polish; PODPIS/PODPISY == SIGNATURE/SIGNATURES) what can be generated in Microsoft Word. Near the 'X' signers' names are updated when the document is signed by each person.
[image]

Thanks for any help.