# How to add digital signature to binary based office document using Java APIs?

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature, .doc

How can i add digital signature to binary based office document (.doc, .ppt ,..) using Java APIs [for example using  XML digital signature specification (JSR 105)] ?
I tried using the example from :
[How to programatically sign an MS office XML document with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522187/how-to-programatically-sign-an-ms-office-xml-document-with-java)

but I get the below error :

> org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Can't
>   open the specified file: 'C:\Users\Desktop\digitalSign\xx2.ppt'   at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:112)
>     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:225)
>     at
>   com.etq.reliance.business.officeIntegration.ooxml.OfficeDocumentSigner.main(OfficeDocumentSigner.java:49)
>   Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file  at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)     at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile.(ZipSecureFile.java:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.openZipFile(ZipHelper.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:110)
>     ... 2 more

Comment: i don't understand your question.  how would you add an xml signature to a binary document?  or do you mean that the signature info would be maintained separately?  if so, how?

Comment: using MS office you can add signature to .doc files, so I need to know how to do that by code ?